# Can you set multiple cURL --write-out variables to bash variables in a single call

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I need to set or access multiple cURL variables so I can access them later in a script. For example:

```
curl -s --write-out "%{http_code} | %{local_ip} | %{time_total}" "http://endpoint.com/payload"
```

Now how can I access http_code or local_ip to do things like add them to an bash array, etc? Is the only option to grep them out of the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe your curl command to a read command :

```
curl -s --write-out "write-out: %{http_code} | %{local_ip} | %{time_total}\n" "http://yahoo.com"  | \
  sed -n '/^write-out:/ s///p' | \
  while IFS='|' read  http_code local_ip time_total; 
    do 
    printf "http_code: %s\nlocal_ip: %s\ntotal_time: %s\n" $http_code $local_ip $time_total; 

    # or in an array
    curlvars=($http_code $local_ip $time_total)
    for data in "${curlvars[@]}"
      do
      printf "%s | " $data
    done
  done
```

I added a `\n` to the write-out string to allow process it as a line.

The sed command extract the write-out line from the curl output.

In the read command you can define a separator and assign all parsed strings to vars.

Comment: Wow, sry for the late response! I'm accepting your answer. I wish there were a cleaner way to do it but it does work.